# Change time selected on mouse click from 30 minutes to an hour

Tags: fullcalendar

Right now when I click on the calendar in the week view, it defaults to 30 minutes slots. I can extend it, but it will always start with 30 minutes.

09:30-10:00
12:00-12:30
17:30-18:00

I would like to change that so it defaults to an hour. Ideally when I click on the calendar, it will start with a 60 minute block.

09:30-10:30
12:00-13:00
17:30-18:30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this option called [defaultTimedEventDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/) but I never succeeded to use it...

However you can modify the event after clicking on the calendar: after the `select` method, you simply calculate the event's end date and you `render` the event:

```
select: function(start, end) {
    end =  $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
    end.add(1, 'hours');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: false
        },
        true // stick the event
    );
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/y8ugsvnL/).

**Edit:** to calculate the end date, I use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which comes with FullCalendar v2. But a Javascript Date() would work too.

Answer (score 3):

In file fullcalendar.min.js
In last line find

```
slotDuration:"00:30:00"
```

Change to

```
slotDuration:"01:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/snapDuration/).

```
snapDuration: "01:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the forceEventDuration to true than you are able to set a time for the defaultTimedEventDuration. Adding the below code it will set 1 hour as a default to the events.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  forceEventDuration : true,
  defaultTimedEventDuration : "01:00:00"
});
```

Sources: 
[forceEventDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/forceEventDuration/)
[defaultTimedEventDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/)

Comment: Except it doesn't, I still have the default 30min duration: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/tnu79n40/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the duration in the select method too like below

```
select: function(arg) {
          calendar.addEvent({
          title: title,
          start: arg.start,
          end: arg.end.getMinutes() +50,
          allDay: arg.allDay
          });
       calendar.unselect()
      }
```